# What are the consequences for a Warforged that does not spend 6 hours in its inactive state?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits, rests, warforged

In the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* (p. 68-69  - the version quoted here is as it appears in [UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf)), a [Warforged has the two following traits](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=8):

> ***Sentry's Rest***. When you take a long rest, you **must** spend at least six hours in an inactive, motionless state, rather than sleeping. [...]
>
> ***Warforged Resilience***. [...] You don't need to sleep and **don't suffer the effects of exhaustion due to lack of rest**, [...]
>
> (Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron, **emphasis mine**)

While Sentry's Rest states the rest must be taken, Warforged Resilience seems to indicate there is no penalty for not doing so.

**What are the actual consequences for a Warforged that does not go inactive during a long rest?**

Comment: Note: the final version of the warforged in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and in the updated version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* has totally removed the bolded section of the "Warforged Resilience" trait (also renamed to "Constructed Resilience"), potentially changing the answer to this question. Are you interested in keeping this question only about the UA version, or would you prefer answers be updated to address the final version of the race?

Comment: @V2Blast May as well let this one stand for the UA and let someone ask about the final version if it comes up.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## You will not receive any benefits of a long rest

This includes Hit Die refresh, Hit Point recovery, spell slots, abilities that refresh on a long rest, etc.

Basically, while you won't suffer the negative effects of skipping a long rest, you also don't enjoy any of the benefits of having taken one.

Comment: Or IOW, you don't actually take a long rest at all.

Comment: I play a Warforged Warlock, and I take guard duty most nights for this reason. I only take a long rest if I've received damage that day.

Comment: @CrimRei I was about to make an edit, but hte language still says they don't need to sleep. I don't think a change is needed.

Comment: @CrimRei Sorry :( And you mind deleting that last comment or editing out the language?